# Security context and unit tests in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I am trying to track down a bug, which may be rights related.

When I run a unit test in Visual Studio 2010, from the UI by right clicking on the test. Does the test execute in the security context of my user, or is it in the context of some Visual Studio test execution context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test runs under the security context of your user account.